# Read and use dates from Firebase in tableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

In my Firebase I have a `timestamp` that I want to read out and populate in a `tableView`

The Firebase structure looks like this:

```
"OpeHS4UhH6YWcK4aPHJWumueCQP2" : {
      "Events" : {
        "Date" : {
          "-LQYDWAKlzTrlTtO1Qiz" : 1541410526186,
          "-LQYspEghK3KE27MlFNE" : 1541421618601,
          "-LQsILjpNqKwLl9XBcQm" : 1541764115618,
          "-LQsYbhf-vl-NnRLTHhK" : 1541768379422
        },
```

So I want to go down the `childByAutoID/Events/Date` and read out all dates and display in a `tableView.

The closest I have gotten is something like this:

```
 var eventDates = [String]() 

    func getEventHistory() {

        let eventHistoryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)/Events/")

        eventHistoryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if  let eventDate = value?["Date"] as? [String:String] {
                self.DateHistoryArray += Array(eventDate.values)

            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Im not able to convert the dates and add them to the array.

Comment: Are you using an auto ID or a user ID as the top key? It's unclear in the question.

Comment: don't know which array you use to fill the table DateHistoryArray  or  eventDates  ? make sure that you fill the correct one

Comment: always track code with breakpoints or logs

Comment: @JenPerson Sorry for being imprecise. The correct path is users/uid/Events/Date/chidlByAutoID : dateInMilleseconds