# Converting timestamp from Firebase and adding to array

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to read a timeStamp from Firebase and append it to an array.

I have made some progress:

```
   var orderDateHistoryArray = [String:Int]() 

func getOrderDates() {

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let orderDateHistoryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)/Orders/")

        orderDateHistoryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // Get dates
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if  let orderDate = value?["Date"] as? [String:Int] {

                self.orderDateHistoryArray += Array(orderDate.values)//This does not conform
                print(orderDate)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

The `print(orderDate)`statement prints:

> ["-LQYspEghK3KE27MlFNE": 1541421618601,
>   "-LQsYbhf-vl-NnRLTHhK": 1541768379422,
>   "-LQYDWAKlzTrlTtO1Qiz": 1541410526186,
>   "-LQsILjpNqKwLl9XBcQm": 1541764115618]

This is `childByAutoID` : `timeInMilliseconds`

So, I want to read out the `timeInMilliseconds`, convert it to a readable `timestamp`and append it to the `orderDateHistoryArray`

Comment: Look for `Date` which can be init with a TimeInterval since 70 (but it's in seconds, so you need to divide by 1000). Quickly done, that's `self.orderDateHistoryArray += Array(orderDate.values).map{ Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval($0/1000))}`

Comment: Isn't that you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289172/read-and-use-dates-from-firebase-in-tableview/53289256#53289256 ??

Answer (score 0):

Those are timestamps. Parse it as a Date object then use [.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to get date.

```js
alert( new Date(1541421618601).toLocaleDateString("en-US") );
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a Swift question, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform your `timestamp` you must, first remove milliseconds on each the values returned by the dictionary.

```
self.orderDateHistoryArray += Array(orderDate.values).map { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval($0/1000)) }
```

In order to get it in a "human way", you need to have a `DateFormatter`. It's on this object where you define how it's presented.

```
extension Date {
  func format(_ dateFormat: String = "dd/MMMM")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
    return formatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

and on a `Date` element you can just call it by `date.format()` or by passing a string `date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX")`